# Eloquent search based on value from cell in CSV not working

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-5, eloquent

I am attempting to populate a field for a new User (company_id) with a value that is being retrieved from the Companies table below:

```
/**
 * Import a CSV file
 * @param File|array $csv File Data
 * @param $tenant
 * @return mixed
 */
public function importCSV(array $csv)
{
    foreach ($csv as $line => $cell)
    {
        try
        {
             (new User)->create([
                'company_id' => self::getCompanyFromId($cell[3]),
                'name' => $cell[5] . " " . $cell[6],
                'address' => $cell[15],
                'zip' => $cell[18],
                'remote_id' => $cell[0],
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Log::info("Failed on Importing CSV - Line $line - " . $e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Log::info("Failed on Importing CSV - Line $line - " . $e->getMessage());

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Get company ID from remote ID
 * @param $id
 * @return int
 */
static public function getCompanyFromId($id)
{
    $company = Company::whereRemoteId($id)->first();

    if ($company){ 
        return $company->id;
    }
    else {
        Log::info("No company with ID " . $id);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is never finding a company, and it should be. I am accessing the correct cells from the csv ($cell[3] is the identifying id that is being checked against the remote_id field in the companies table), and writing a query that compares the two from the command line is yielding the desired result.

What is incorrect in the code below, and why would it not be working?

Comment: Did you check if `$company = Company::whereRemoteId($id)->first();` is returning the company ?
Also may I suggest you to rename getCompanyFromId() for getCompanyFromRemoteId() which would be more real

Comment: Good tip on the renaming, and it doesn't seem to be getting it.

Comment: Can you try this : `$company = Company::where('remote_id', $id)->first();`

Comment: Hmm.. Strange, no companies at all are being returned which is the problem, I guess. Would this most likely be a setting with the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that the Company table wasn't accessible for some reason so I altered the helper method as seen below:

```
static public function getCompanyFromRemoteId($id)
{
    $company = DB::table('companies')->whereRemoteId($id)->first();

    if ($company){ 
        return $company->id;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Works now.